# Keeping type information when serializing / deserializing

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, serialization

I have the following class:

```
public class Stuff {
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public Dictionary<string,object> Values {get;set;}
}

public class ComplexType {
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string Id {get;set;}
}
```

Now an object could contain something like this:

```
var myStuff=new Stuff ();
myStuff.Id=1;
myStuff.Values=new Dictionary<string,object>();
myStuff.Values.Add("magic",new ComplexType { Id=3, Name="Gonzo" };
```

When I serialize that data everything is fine:

```
string data=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myStuff)
```

After deserializing however, the type from the complextype is lost:

```
Stuff ret=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (data,typeof(Stuff));
```

**The Value from the complex datatype is
`object {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject}` instead of `object {MyNamespace.ComplexType}`**

And when I try to return this as part of a JsonResult:

```
return new JsonResult { Data = ret };
```

The value does not contain any data but an empty array if I call that method from a browser.

So how can I make sure serializing/deserializing does not destroy the type information? I **do undestand** why this happens: The string containing the serialized data does not contain any type information at all and on deserializing the method cannot "guess" what type this might have been.

Is there a way to serialize/deserialize the data without losing the type information? Preferred Format would be Json but if I need to use another serialization-format (that saves that information) that would be ok, too.

*Note: The dictionary may contain different type of values, so the value must be of type "object"*

Answer (score 0):

I did not really solve the original problem, but the symptoms. I was able to return a valid result from within MVC that contains the data required by not returning a JsonResult, but an ActionResult:

```
public class MyResult:ActionResult {
  private JObject _data;
  public MyResult(object data) {
    _data=JObject.FromObject(data);
  }
  public override ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) {
    var response=context.HttpContext.Response;
    response.ContentType="application/json";
    response.Write(_data.ToString());
  }
}
```

and then return this:

```
return new MyResult(ret);
```

The ActionResult returns a valid response that can be used by a Get-Request. JsonResult didn't.

*Note: As this works fine for my specific problem it does only partly answer the question I asked. That's why I will leave this open if someone might have a more generic solution.*